# Xamarin Studio: Rebuild project error with error : The "DebugType" parameter is not supported by the "XamlCTask" task

Tags: xml, compiler-errors, xamarin-studio, rebuild

I have managed to rebuild the project by remove the line `DebugType = "$(DebugType)"` in the xml file below. What does this line really do and why it can fix my problem. I have the error because I pulling the new code from source tree.

```
<Target Name="XamlC">
    <XamlCTask
        Assembly = "$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)"
        ReferencePath = "@(ReferencePath)"
        Verbosity = "2"
        OptimizeIL = "true"
        DebugSymbols = "$(DebugSymbols)"
        />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply restarting Visual Studio and doing a rebuild in the solution.

I did nothing, and the project worked.

Following this thought, in your case, restarting Xamarin Studio should resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instruction here fixed it for me: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95724/xamarin-forms-2-3-4-247-update-project-wont-build

I had to close Visual Studio, delete all bin/ and obj/ directories in ALL projects, and then restart. Simply cleaning or deleting the directories in a single project without restarting did not work.

Not sure if it had anything to do with it, but it seemed to have started after a renamed an assembly. iOS did not experience this problem.